# JSON update in PHP : duplication

Tags: php, json

I have a strange issue when I'm trying to update a json in my database.
This is my code :

```
// Update content of user cart                    
$contentJSON = json_decode($userCart['content'],true);

$newJSONContent;

$wineNotExist = true;
$index = 1;
foreach($contentJSON as $key) {
    // Update content if wine is already in user cart
    if ($key['wineId'] === $wineId) {
        
        $contentObject->wineId = $wineId;
        $contentObject->wineQuantity = $key['wineQuantity'] + $wineQuantity;

        $dataIndex = strval($index);

        $newJSONContent->$dataIndex = $contentObject;

        $wineNotExist = false;
    } else {
        $contentObject->wineId = $key['wineId'];
        $contentObject->wineQuantity = $key['wineQuantity'];

        $dataIndex = strval($index);

        $newJSONContent->$dataIndex = $contentObject;
    }
    $index++;
}

if ($wineNotExist) {
    $dataKey = strval($index);

    $contentObject->wineId = $wineId;
    $contentObject->wineQuantity = $wineQuantity;

    $newJSONContent->$dataKey = $contentObject;
}
```

So, I decided to build a new JSON and parse the former; moreover if json not contains the wineId we created a new data input in JSON but this section replaces previous key by the right one and create the right one as you can see in AJAX response here :

Response when it's the same wineId

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "message": "This wine has been added to your cart",
  "content": {
    "1": {
      "wineId": 2,
      "wineQuantity": 3
    }
  },
  "index": true
}
```

Response when wineId is not contains in cart

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "message": "This wine has been added to your cart",
  "content": {
    "1": {
      "wineId": 5,
      "wineQuantity": 1
    },
    "2": {
      "wineId": 5,
      "wineQuantity": 1
    }
  },
  "index": true
}
```

I don't understand why the instruction in if replaces previous value, do you have an idea why ?

When I use another variable name for contentObject in if instruction, the code works but why ? Because $contentObject is a local variable in foreach loop

Sorry for my english, I'm French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with this code, so the problem is that $contentObject has the previous value whereas it's a local varibale, is it specific to PHP ?

```
// Update content of user cart                    
                $contentJSON = json_decode($userCart['content'],true);

                $newJSONContent;

                $wineNotExist = true;
                $index = 1;
                foreach($contentJSON as $key) {
                    // Update content if wine is already in user cart
                    if ($key['wineId'] === $wineId) {
                        $contentObject=null;
                        $contentObject->wineId = $wineId;
                        $contentObject->wineQuantity = $key['wineQuantity'] + $wineQuantity;

                        $dataIndex = strval($index);

                        $newJSONContent->$dataIndex = $contentObject;

                        $wineNotExist = false;
                    } else {
                        $contentObject=null;
                        $contentObject->wineId = $key['wineId'];
                        $contentObject->wineQuantity = $key['wineQuantity'];

                        $dataIndex = strval($index);

                        $newJSONContent->$dataIndex = $contentObject;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
    
                if ($wineNotExist) {
                    $contentObject=null;
                    $dataKey = strval($index);

                    $contentObject->wineId = $wineId;
                    $contentObject->wineQuantity = $wineQuantity;

                    $newJSONContent->$dataKey = $contentObject;
                }
```